# Can I change variables in class methods from Main method?

Tags: c#, variables, methods, scope

I'm learning C# and currently making a Naughts and Crosses game.
I have reached a point where I have a boolean variable that decides the player turn, an input where the player would like to place their turn and the actual board in it's own class.

Here is where I'm stuck. I would like to take the player input and use it to change the board but can't figure out how to access it from the Main method.

Below is my code. playerinput refers to a 1-9 place on the board and printer is a Board object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ---
        ---
        ---

        int playerinput = printer.GetNumber();

        if (!currentPlayer)
        {
        // I want to add code here that takes playerinput 
        // and changes the corresponding place on the board.
        }
```

And here is the actual board.

```
    public class Board
{ ----
public void PrintBoard()
    {
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        var c = 3;
        var d = 4;
        var e = 5;
        var f = 6;
        var g = 7;
        var h = 8;
        var i = 9;

        System.Console.Writeline(string.Format(@" {0} | {1} | {2}
-----------
 {3} | {4} | {5} 
-----------
 {6} | {7} | {8} ", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i));
```

So I need to take the playerinput and change the corresponding letter in the PrintBoard method. As long as I can change these variables I should be OK.

One of the difficulties when searching for an answer was knowing how to word it properly so any advice or additional reading on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the issue exactly ? You didn't show how you're using `Board`.

Comment: Sorry, after 'if (!currentPlayer)' I want to add some code that takes playerinput and changes the corresponding variable in the PrintBoard method. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in `PrintBoard` aren't persistent - they last at most as long as the method. When you call `PrintBoard` again, any changes will be lost.

You need to declare the board in a scope that lasts long enough. For example, the `Main` method itself. You already have an instance of the `Board` object, so that would be the obvious place to put it - just declare those variables as fields, rather than as locals in a method.

One of the methods on your `Board` object might be handling the player input; that would just be a method that takes the player input as an argument, and update the board accordingly.

As another suggestion, consider reading up on arrays - they are a convenient way of managing structured data like the grid you have here. You could do something like this:

```
public class Board
{
  private char[,] data = new char[3, 3]; // A 2D array of ' ', 'X' or 'O'

  // Returns false for invalid input
  public bool HandleInput(int playerInput, char player)
  {
    if (player != 'X' && player != 'O') return false; // Bad player

    // Get coördinates from the 1-9 input
    var x = (playerInput - 1) % 3;
    var y = (playerInput - 1) / 3;

    if (x < 0 || x > 2 || y < 0 || y > 2) return false; // Out-of-board-exception

    if (data[x, y] != ' ') return false; // Non-empty cell

    data[x, y] = player; // Set the new cell contents

    return true;
  }

  public void Print()
  {
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++)
      {
        Console.Write(data[x, y]);
        Console.Write(" | ");
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("---------");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to your `PrintBoard` method. Could look like this

```
public void PrintBoard(int playerInput)
{
    ....
```

When you are calling the `PrintBoard` method from your `Main` method you can give the user input to your method and use it in it.

Could look like this (assuming `board` is an instance of your `Board` class.

```
int playerinput = printer.GetNumber();
board.PrintBoard(playerInput);
```

You could have a look at [Method Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to the method PrintBoard() and can pass the parameters from the Main method like PrintBoard(1,2):

```
public void PrintBoard(int a, int b)
```

And then you can assign the numbers in the PrintBoard methods like:

```
     public void PrintBoard(int a, int b)
    {
    //Can print the numbers directly.
    }
```